# SystemMediaTransportControl GetForCurrentView() fails in audio background task on Desktop Device Family (UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, background-task

I'm trying to bring over my C# WP 8.1 Background Audio Task to UWP and everything works, except trying to get the UVC using Windows.Media.Playback.SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView() throws the current exception on Desktop devices: "Could Not Find an appropriate view to be associated with this instance of the MediaPlaybackControl. Please make sure that a view has been initialized".
Is it simply a behavior that has yet to be converged, or do I need to control and update the UVC via my app on Desktop class device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an API change in Windows 10. It seems that you should use BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls.  This is not in the documentation yet. You can find it in the Windows 10 sample repository: [https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/backgroundaudio](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio)

Comment: Is there a better sample as this sample has bugs.

Comment: Not that I know. The git hub repository is updated quite often so a fix can be made at some point. It seems that you can submit your own bugs here; https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues